# how to filter the rows I read from google-sheets with Java API

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to use Google-sheet API to read only rows with empty cell in column X ?

This is the way i read from google-sheets today
but I don't see any "filter" method.

```
    final ValueRange values = service.spreadsheets()
            .values()
            .get(spreadSheetId, range)
            .execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check the [ConditionType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#conditiontype) then use the `BLANK`.

> The cell's value must be empty. Supported by conditional formatting and filters. Requires no [ConditionValues](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#BooleanCondition.FIELDS.values).

Here's another reference: [FilterCriteria](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria) which you  may use for showing/hiding rows in a filter or filter view. Use the `hiddenValues[]` *(Values that should be hidden.)* and the `condition` *(A condition that must be true for values to be shown.)* fields.

Comment: thanks. can you give a code example + how can I know the original row number? as i want to write data to these blank-column rows